# Как при клике по кнопке открывать гиперссылку?

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi сделать так, чтобы при клике по кнопке открывалась гиперссылка (веб-страница)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А разницы нету никакой. Просто теперь в обработчике `onClick` кнопки вы используете код:

```
ShellExecute(Application.Handle,PChar('open'),
 PChar('http://hashcode.ru'), PChar(0), nil, SW_NORMAL);
```

Т.е. примерно будет все выглядеть так:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //проверки и прочее
  ShellExecute(Application.Handle,PChar('open'),
   PChar('http://hashcode.ru'), PChar(0), nil, SW_NORMAL);
end;
```

Декорации для кнопки, сами придумаете?

Comment: не забудьте в uses добавить shellapi

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите открыть страницу в браузере на вашей форме, то что-то типа такого:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('сайт на который нужно перейти');
```

Comment: В принципе это тоже ответ, хоть и плохой, но освещает другую возможную сторону решения.